# How to build a sandboxed cabal project with a custom version of a dependency that is not on hackage (e.g. a checkout from github)

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

If a have a library checked out locally that builds with cabal that is used by an application. I would like to build my application against the the local library rather than something from hackage but I'm not sure how to do this. This seems like something I should be able to do, I'm just don't seem to be able to work out how.

**Sandboxing**

In case it matters or complicates things, the application is in a cabal sandbox with the `cabal-sandbox-config` file in the route directory of the application.

**What I'm Trying to accomplish**

I'm building Yesod application and I want to tweak the behaviour of one of the dependencies (shakespeare). I would like to build my application against my tweaked version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `cabal sandbox add-source`, which is designed specifically for this use case.

Example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/SomeUser/SomeDependency
$ cd /path/to/my-project
$ cabal sandbox add-source /path/to/SomeDependency
$ cabal build
```

As a bonus, if you later update `SomeDependency` and try to rebuild `my-project`, `cabal` will notice that and reinstall `SomeDependency`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

You can just clone the project, and then run a cabal install in the cloned directory.
`git clone https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare.git`

This will give you a directory `shakespeare` which will contain a `.cabal` file.

So just enter the directory and run a `cabal install`. This will install `shakespeare`. Now continue with installing your project.

The key point:

You need to install shakespeare yourself first so that when you compile your own project, `ghc` or `cabal` doesn't try to install the shakespeare dependency (from hackage by default) on its own.

**Option 2:**

- Install [hackage-server](https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server)
- Upload a copy of shakespeare (your tweaked version) to your local hackage
- Edit your cabal config to prioritize your local hackage over the haskell-hackage

> *remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive*
>
> *remote-repo: local.hackage:http://local.hackage/packages/archive*

This might make sense if you're going to be tweaking several packages, but you're probably better off not doing this because among other things, keeping track of updates to your tweaked versions is going to be a nightmare.